# Ios Swift PieChart

Tags: ios, swift, ios-charts

How can I display the legend values in ios pie chart? I was able to get only the non zero values. Can anyone help?

```
func updateChartData12()  {

    let chart = PieChartView(frame: self.view.frame)
    // 2. generate chart data entries
    let track = ["Income", "Expense", "Wallet", "Bank"]
    let money = [650, 456.13, 0, 0]

    var entries = [PieChartDataEntry]()
    for (index, value) in money.enumerated() {
        let entry = PieChartDataEntry()
        if value != 0 {
            entry.y = value
            entry.label = track[index]
            entries.append( entry)
        }


    }

    // 3. chart setup
    let set = PieChartDataSet( values: entries, label: "")
    // this is custom extension method. Download the code for more details.
    var colors: [UIColor] = []

    for _ in 0..<money.count {
        let red = Double(arc4random_uniform(256))
        let green = Double(arc4random_uniform(256))
        let blue = Double(arc4random_uniform(256))
        let color = UIColor(red: CGFloat(red/255), green: CGFloat(green/255), blue: CGFloat(blue/255), alpha: 1)
        colors.append(color)
    }
    set.colors = colors
    let data = PieChartData(dataSet: set)
    chart.data = data
    chart.noDataText = "No data available"
    // user interaction



    let d = Description()

    chart.chartDescription = d
    chart.centerText = "Pie Chart"
    chart.holeRadiusPercent = 0.2
    chart.transparentCircleColor = UIColor.clear
    self.view.addSubview(chart)

}
```

I am using this code..But I need to display total y values i.e legend at the bottom

Answer (score 0):

Your pie chart is greater than 100%. The data I have is intended to show a total that is over 100% and That the reason it's not work.

```
let track = ["Income", "Expense", "Wallet", "Bank"]
let money = [650, 456.13, 0, 0]
```

So use following money array if it's work fine then you would like to check is there build in method to ensure the sum of percentages in the pie chart is 100%

```
let money = [65, 35, 0, 0]
```

Comment: ok..But I need to display the non zero values on the pie chart and all the legend at the bottom even if has zero value. Any help please for this solution.

Comment: In a pie chart no slice is shown for a zero value, so unlike other chart
types you don't really need to cater for it. Or, do you mean not display
Legend Entries with zero values. That could be done with a macro, though it
would need to be more then 0 values change.

Comment: the legend is showing the only track of Income and  Expense  becouse it has non -zero values. But i need to display the legend of the total track even it has zero values .. And on slice it should not display anything if it is zero..I am getting slice perfectly but am not getting legend totally when it is zero value

Comment: @roshan is this array working let money = [65, 35, 0, 0]?

Comment: let money = [65, 35, 0, 0]? It is working ..The legend displays first two values .. and the remaining two values aren't displaying ..How can i display even it has zero ..Legend shoud display all labels.

Comment: use this array let money = [65, 33, 1, 1] b'coz pie chart no slice is shown for a zero value.

Comment: Am ok with the pie chart. But if there is no value with pie chart  ..the legend is not showing related text in the bottom so in that situation is there any solution on that all legends values should be shown at the bottom under pie chart .

Comment: @roshan pls share your screen shot. i didn't understand what you face problem.